# IOS App that allows you to takes photos every X seconds and saving it in the camera toll (no time lapse)

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, photos, video

community

Is there an IOS app that allows you to capture photos every X seconds and automatically saves it in the camera roll (not like a time lapse that puts it in a single video)

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

This app does the trick. It will save files to the camera roll. You can turn off the movie rendering.

IntervalCam - Create Timelapse Movies by TritheCat Studio
https://appsto.re/us/RunTR.i